# How to add search button on Android Google maps ?

Tags: android

I want to put the search button in google maps in Android application (like the way I added zoom controls). However, I am not able to find a way to add it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a search button, you have to implement a the Reverse Geocoding, using a GeoCoder that receives your searched Strings from a EditText so with the coordinates obtained you can set a geopoint in the MapOverlay to show the searched position on the map.

For more info about Google Maps geocoding see:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Answer (score 0):

This question is too vague. What "search button" are you talking about? Do you mean a SearchView? There's a search widget in the maps.google.com web interface, but that's not the standard Android design. The Android Google Maps app uses a SearchView with history and autocomplete.

Comment: I am talking about a search box where if users enter a location, it is displayed on the map. Can we implement this in Android google maps API?